# shell - mysqldump works with echo but not directly

Tags: shell, mysql, variable

Im preparing a shell script which will take mysql table dump with where clause.
Im passing table name and where condition from a parameter.

**Backup command:**

```
mysqldump -u root-p'pass'  db blocked_reasons --where=" created_time <  DATE(Now() - INTERVAL 2 month)" > test.sql
```

**Run this command with parameters:**

```
tbl="blocked_reasons"
where="--where="\""created_time <  DATE(Now() - INTERVAL 2 month)"\"""
```

**verify with echo:**

```
echo " mysqldump -u root -p db $tbl $where > test.sql"
 mysqldump -u root-p db blocked_reasons  --where="created_time <  DATE(Now() - INTERVAL 2 month)" > test.sql
```

But when I start to execute this command Im getting errors:

```
mysqldump: Couldn't find table: "<"
```

Comment: I'd get rid of some of the spacing in your query in the --where clause. Take a look at this for an example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5658284/how-to-use-mysqldump-for-a-portion-of-a-table

Comment: Yeah, seems its spacing issue. But its a sting right, how can I add space inside it?

Comment: I read this on a SO question. ```Double quotes will corrupt your string.```

Comment: Ah yeah, thatll do it.. I was on the fence about suggesting to swap the double quotes to single quotes originally.

Comment: Never use -p'pass' in your backup scripts. This can be spotted by regular user in /proc/[PID]/cmdline. Instead simply assign your password to MYSQL_PWD variable within script before launching mysqldump